# Getting error "Cannot access org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle"

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

I am trying to create client for Web socket implementation. Getting above error while doing setConnectTimeout.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(20);
```

Can someone let me know why this error is coming?

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a way yet?

Comment: me too. could you answer your question if you found an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had this message for missing the http dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version> 9.4.28.v20200408</version>
</dependency>
```